# Postgresql use json_populate_recordset can not use empty value

Tags: postgresql

When I use this sql to test json_populate_recordset ,there is no error:

```
select 'name',(json_populate_recordset(null::"trn_rebatesys_20mstcontractdetail",'[
        {
            "s_line_no":1,
            "departmentcd":30,
            "catagorycd":2,
            "jan":"",
            "seriescd":"",
            "f_exclude":0
        }

    ]')).s_line_no,(json_populate_recordset(null::"trn_rebatesys_20mstcontractdetail",'[
        {
            "s_line_no":1,
            "departmentcd":30,
            "catagorycd":2,
            "jan":"",
            "seriescd":"",
            "f_exclude":0
        }

    ]')).departmentcd
```

Result:
[image]

But when I change the second`"departmentcd":30` to `"departmentcd":""`,
the error message said `Error: type integer input syntax is invalid: ""`,how to fix it?How do deal empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `null` keyword

```
select  json_populate_recordset(null::"test",'[{"id":null, "title":null}]');
 json_populate_recordset
-------------------------
 (,)
(1 row)
```